# WPF character spacing irregular in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, code-behind

I have a problem with character spacing.

Basically I have something like this which comes from a txt file:

```
****************
*System Details*
****************
```

Looks nice and uniform, however, when I open have this go into a RichTextBox this happens:

Irregular character spacing example:

[image]

I've tried all different properties to try and stretch it, render it etc. but nothing works.

The data is coming in from code-behind OpenDialogBox that stores all the lines of the file in a string[]. A foreach loop then sends the lines into the RTB. (It needs to be a loop as each line gets checked)

Any help it greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a font choice problem. By default WPF uses Segoe UI on Windows 7 and above which is a non-[monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). This means that each character will not necessarily take up the same amount of space as each other character leading to issues if you are trying to align characters between lines. The easiest way to get alignment to work is by changing the font to a monospaced font by setting the [FontFamily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontfamily%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the RichTextBox.

Comment: Another case of me looking into things to much and not looking at the simple things :)

Many thanks for this @Mitch Connor. I've changed the font to Courier and all is sweet! :D